# how to get ios browser on iphone to view web pages on my local server for testing?

Tags: ios, webserver

I have an iOS device. I'm developing some html 5 pages that I'd like to view on my iphone while developing. Is this possible. I tried accessing my local server's ip and it wouldn't connect. I'm not sure if there's something else I should try.

I also tried an my Android device evo shift 4g and same thing...it wouldn't connect using the ip.

Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to mention that my local webserver is running IIS 7.0 on Windows 7 professional desktop. This is my home network. The iphone is connected to my home wifi.

Comment: I trying to access via the IP on my machine...did an ipconfig and using the 192.x.x.x ip. THis is not a public IP.

Comment: it's browsable from other computers on my network but not sure how to get it viewable on my iphone

Comment: how would I check my phones wifi ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Is the local server running correctly configured apache, or some other server software? Can you access the local pages from a browser on the local server itself? Is the firewall letting port 80 connections in?

Answer (score 0):

Are the WiFi devices in the same subnet as the server?  What are the IP addresses of the phones?  That could happen if you have a wireless router connected to a wired router, and the wireless router is running its own separate DHCP server.  Have you tested from computers that are connected to the wireless network?

There shouldn't be anything that prevents an iPhone or an Android phone from connecting to an IP address that it can resolve.  I've never had a problem connecting to a (public) IP address from either an iPhone or an Android phone.

Comment: You can check your iPhone's IP address by going to the Settings app, tapping "Wi-Fi", and tapping the little blue arrow-in-a-circle on the right side of the selected WiFi network (it's a bit hard to hit, so you might have to tap more than once).

Answer (score 0):

I'm running IIS 7 on Windows 7 Professional. Had the same problem. It's a firewall issue. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Windows Firewall\Allowed Programs and enable "World Wide Web Services (HTTP)" for "Home/Work (Private)". That worked for me. As my iPhone is in the same network, I now can access my test server by its IP.